# glTexImage2D returns invalid value

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I cannot find a reason why it would. Here is how I am calling it

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, surf->w, surf->h, 0, data_fmt, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surf->pixels)
```

width and height parameters are 872 639
and internal format is GL_RGBA

What might be the problem? I checked https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es1.1/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml and it looks fine (unless width or height is greater than max texture size which I doubt or internal format RGBA is not supported which also not likely)

Here is the full code

```
out << "loading " << fileName << "\n";
dimensions.setZero();
name = fileName;
this->repeat = repeat;

SDL_Surface* surf = IMG_Load(fileName.c_str());
if (surf == NULL)
{
    out << "surface_error: " << fileName << " " << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
    hasError = true;
    return;
}

GLenum data_fmt;
if (surf->format->BytesPerPixel == 4)
{
    data_fmt = GL_RGBA;
}
else if (surf->format->BytesPerPixel == 3)
{
    data_fmt = GL_RGB;
}
else if (surf->format->BytesPerPixel == 1)
{
    data_fmt = GL_RED;
}
else
{
    assert(false);
}
GL_CALL(glGenTextures(1, &gTexture));
GL_CALL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gTexture));
GL_CALL(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, surf->w, surf->h, 0, data_fmt, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surf->pixels));
if (hadGLError)
{
    out << data_fmt << " " << surf->w << " " << surf->h << "\n";
}
GL_CALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
GL_CALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
dimensions = IntVec2(surf->w, surf->h);

glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL_CALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, repeat ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
GL_CALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, repeat ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
GL_CALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
GL_CALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR));

SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
```

`GL_CALL` checks for `glGetError` and it is set to `GL_INVALID_VALUE`, 0x0501 after `glTexImage2D`. The game crashes on trying to set wrap parameters

Comment: What GL version are you actually using? Also, what is "he game crashes on trying to set wrap parameters" supposed to mean? A crash in `glTexParameteri` would be more than weird.

Comment: @derhass I set GL version to 3.2 using SDL_GL_SetAttribute if that is what you are asking. Sadly the game crashes before the client was able to print its actual GL version. The game crashes on line that sets GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, I dont know how. Here is the call stack

https://justpaste.it/1feu9 

and the source https://github.com/shultays/bloodworks/blob/master/game/source/cTexture.cpp

Comment: In your glTexImage2D call, why aren't you using data_fmt for both internalformat and format? What if they are different? Also, I don't think you can generate a mipmap for textures which aren't a power of two. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430608/glgeneratemipmap-non-power-of-2

Comment: @Rabbid76, good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Most likely it crashes because `glGenerateMipmap` is not available or not properly loaded.

Comment: And no, tou do not request a 3.2 context. Your are using a legacy context and set those SDL attributes afterwards, which is not going to do anything.

Comment: I think the problem was I was not properly initialing opengl, which was causing all sort of weirdness. I made quite a few changes yesterday and will resolve this close this question

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was caused by something else, opengl was not properly initted.